# Almost identical recursive functions

Tags: language-agnostic, design-principles

I have a function called `myFunction1` whose definition is the following:

```
function myFunction1()
{
    if condition1 then
        doSomething1();
        myFunction1();
    else if condition2 then
        doSomething2();
        myFunction1();
    else if condition3 then
        doSomething3();
        myFunction1();
    else throw Exception;
}
```

Now I want to write a second function `myFunction2` which is almost identical to `myFunction1` except for a single case, i.e.,

```
function myFunction2()
{
    if condition1 then
        doSomething4();
        myFunction2();
    else if condition2 then
        doSomething2();
        myFunction2();
    else if condition3 then
        doSomething3();
        myFunction2();
    else throw Exception; 
}
```

Note that it is only the first `if` which differs from `myFuction1`. How could I write `myFuction2` so as to avoid duplicating code?

Answer (score 0):

If it is easy to read and maintenance, have some duplicates is good!

Answer (score 0):

If it's a functional language then refactoring this is easy. Just take out the difference and pass it in as an argument:

```
function myGenericFunction1(theThingToDo)
{
    if condition1 then
        theThingToDo();
        myFunction1();
    else if condition2 then
        doSomething2();
        myFunction1();
    else if condition3 then
        doSomething3();
        myFunction1();
    else throw Exception;
}
```

Now you can either use it directly:

```
myGenericFunction1(doSomething1);
myGenericFunction1(doSomething4);
```

Or use it to create your two functions:

```
function myFunction1 () {
    myGenericFunction1(doSomething1);
}

function myFunction2 () {
    myGenericFunction1(doSomething4);
}

myFunction1();
myFunction2();
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a functional language, you can add a parameter to a single method:

```
function myFunction(case)
{
    if condition1 then
        if case == 1 then
          doSomething1();
        else
          doSomething4();
        myFunction(case);
    else if condition2 then
        doSomething2();
        myFunction(case);
    else if condition3 then
        doSomething3();
        myFunction(case);
    else throw Exception;
}
```

Or, depending on your actual case, it might make sense to pass doSomething1/4 as a function parameter, to avoid the if. That makes the code simpler when there are more possibilities.